# Cannot recibe firebase messaging on React Native iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

I want to display Firebase Messaging messages in React Native for iOS, and I wrote this code from te official documentation. **I'm working with a MacBook Air and a physical iPhone 12**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      Alert.alert('A new FCM message arrived!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
}
```

[The guide that i use](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage/ios-setup)

and when I print with  console.log this ->

```
  const requestPermission = async () => {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
    const APNS = await messaging().getAPNSToken();

    console.log("authStatus = ", authStatus); 
    console.log("token = ", fcmToken);
    console.log("token APNS = ", APNS);
    console.log('Firebase inicializado:', firebase.app().name);
    console.log('Firebase :' , firebase.app())
  };
```

and it works correctly!

```
LOG  Este es mi token -> token
LOG  token =  token
LOG  token APNS =  apns
LOG  Firebase inicializado: [DEFAULT]
LOG  Firebase : {"_automaticDataCollectionEnabled": true, "_deleteApp": [Function bound deleteApp], "_deleted": false, "_initialized": true, "_name": "[DEFAULT]", "_nativeInitialized": true, "_options": {"apiKey": "apikey", "appId": "1:XXXXX:ios:XXXXX", "clientId": "XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com", "messagingSenderId": "XXXXX", "projectId": "XXXXX", "storageBucket": "XXXXX.appspot.com"}}
LOG  subscribing to topic XXXX
LOG  subscribing to topic XXXX
LOG  subscribing to topic XXXX
LOG  subscribing to topic XXXX
LOG  subscribing to topic XXXX-eb82-4f0b-a65f-c4be1b3ef983
LOG  subscribing to topic XXXXX-eb82-4f0b-a65f-c4be1b3ef983_XXXX
LOG  subscribing to topic XXXXX-eb82-4f0b-a65f-c4be1b3ef983_XXXX
LOG  subscribing to topic XXXXX-eb82-4f0b-a65f-c4be1b3ef983_XXXX
LOG  subscribing to topic XXXX
LOG  subscribing to topic XXXX
LOG  subscribing to topic XXXX
LOG  subscribing to topic XXXX
LOG  subscribing to topic XXXX
```

this is my node modules.

```
{
  "name": "condominos",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "empezar": "npx react-native start",
    "dev": "npx react-native run-android",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "release": "npx react-native run-android --variant=release"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@notifee/react-native": "^7.0.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.1.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "8.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^15.7.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-file-system": "^14.1.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-localization": "~13.0.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~14.1.0",
    "expo-sharing": "^10.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "i18n-js": "^3.9.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "patch-package": "^6.5.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1285.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.39.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^15.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-selector": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

this is my podFile

```
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/package.json')"`), "native_modules")

require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'Podfile.properties.json'))) rescue {}

platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '12.0'
install! 'cocoapods',
  :deterministic_uuids => false

pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true 
pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
pod 'Firebase/Messaging', :modular_headers => true

target 'condominos' do
  use_expo_modules!
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_frameworks! :linkage => podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks'].to_sym if podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks']

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled] || podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes',
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Dir.pwd}/.."
  )

  # Uncomment to opt-in to using Flipper
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work
  #
  # if !ENV['CI']
  #   use_flipper!()
  # end


  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end

  post_integrate do |installer|
    begin
      expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
  end

end
```

and this is my full code in App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { LogBox, Text, View } from "react-native";
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import { ThemeProvider } from "react-native-elements";
import { AppNavigation } from "./app/navigation/Navigation";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import Toast from "react-native-toast-message";
import { toastConfig } from "./app/utils/toastConfig";
import { theme } from "./app/utils";
import { en } from "./app/utils/multiLenguaje/en";
import { es } from "./app/utils/multiLenguaje/es";
import * as Localization from "expo-localization";
import i18n from "i18n-js";
import messaging from "@react-native-firebase/messaging";
import notifee, {
  AndroidImportance,
  AndroidVisibility,EventType
} from "@notifee/react-native";
import { getTopics } from "./app/screens/Notificaciones/NotificacionesScreen.service";
import { getUser } from "./app/screens/Account/AccountService";
import { Platform } from "react-native";
import SplashScreen from "./app/components/SplashScreen/SplashScreen";
import RNSplashScreen from "react-native-splash-screen";
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';

LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();
export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [locale, setLocale] = useState(Localization.locale);
  const [showSplash, setShowSplash] = useState(true);

  i18n.fallbacks = true;
  i18n.translations = { en, es };
  i18n.locale = locale;

  async function loadFonts() {
    const fonts = await Font.loadAsync({
      "lato-regular": require("./assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf"),
      "lato-bold": require("./assets/fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf"),
    });
    setFontsLoaded(true);
  }

  const subscribeTopic = async (topic) => {
    console.log("subscribing to topic", topic);
    await messaging().subscribeToTopic(topic);
  };

  const unsubscribeTopic = async (topic) => {
    console.log("unsubscribing to topic", topic);
    await messaging().unsubscribeFromTopic(topic);
  };

  messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
    console.log('Message received in the background!', remoteMessage);
});
  const fetchTopics = async () => {
    let user = JSON.parse(await getUser());
    if (user == null) return;
    let topics = await getTopics(user.entidad.id);
    let topicsActive = topics.filter((t) => t.estatus == "ACTIVO");
    let topicsInactive = topics.filter((t) => t.estatus != "ACTIVO");
    topicsActive.forEach(async (item) => {
      await subscribeTopic(item.topic);
    });
    topicsInactive.forEach(async (item) => {
      await unsubscribeTopic(item.topic);
    });
  };

  const requestPermission = async () => {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
    const APNS = await messaging().getAPNSToken();

    console.log("authStatus = ", authStatus); 
    console.log("token = ", fcmToken);
    console.log("token APNS = ", APNS);
    console.log('Firebase inicializado:', firebase.app().name);
    console.log('Firebase :' , firebase.app())
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    loadFonts();
    requestPermission();
    fetchTopics();
    RNSplashScreen.hide();
  
    if (requestPermission){
      // rregresa el token del dispositivo
      messaging().getToken().then(token => {
        console.log("Este es mi token ->" , token);
      });
    }
    else {
      console.log("Failed Token Status", authStatus);
    }

    DisplayNotificationPrueba();
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      console.log('A new FCM message arrived!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
      DisplayNotification(remoteMessage);
    });
    return unsubscribe;


  }, []);


  messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
    console.log('Message handled in the background!!', remoteMessage);
  });

  async function DisplayNotification(remoteMessage) {
   
    // Crear un canal
    const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
      id: "messages",
      name: "Private Messages",
      badge: true,
      importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
      vibration: true,
      lights: true,
      visibility: AndroidVisibility.PUBLIC,
    });
    console.log(remoteMessage);
    // Display a notification
    await notifee.displayNotification({
      title: remoteMessage.notification.title,
      body: remoteMessage.notification.body,
      android: {
        channelId,
        smallIcon: "ic_small_icon", // optional, defaults to 'ic_launcher'.
        color: "#2D2E82",
      },
      ios:{
        sound: 'default',
        channelId,
        smallIcon: "ic_small_icon", // optional, defaults to 'ic_launcher'.
        color: "#2D2E82",
      }
    });
  }


  async function DisplayNotificationPrueba() {
   
    // Create a channel
    const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
      id: "messages",
      name: "Private Messages",
      badge: true,
      importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
      vibration: true,
      lights: true,
      visibility: AndroidVisibility.PUBLIC,
    });
    
    // Display a notification
    await notifee.displayNotification({
      title: "mensaje de prueba",
      body: "no hay nada",
      android: {
        channelId,
        smallIcon: "ic_small_icon", // optional, defaults to 'ic_launcher'.
        color: "#2D2E82",
      },
      ios:{
        sound: 'default',
        channelId,
        smallIcon: "ic_small_icon", // optional, defaults to 'ic_launcher'.
        color: "#2D2E82",
      }
    });
  }

  //if (showSplash && Platform.OS == 'ios') return <SplashScreen />

  if (fontsLoaded) {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <AppNavigation />
        </NavigationContainer>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
        <Toast config={toastConfig} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

and my index.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import notifee, { EventType } from '@notifee/react-native';
import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/messaging'
import App from './App';

firebase.messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (
    remoteMessage
) => {
    // Increment the count by 1
    console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
    await notifee.incrementBadgeCount();
})

notifee.onBackgroundEvent(async ({ type, detail }) => {
    const { notification, pressAction } = detail;
    console.log('Background event', type, detail);
    // Check if the user pressed the "Mark as read" action
    if (type === EventType.ACTION_PRESS && pressAction.id === 'mark-as-read') {
        await notifee.decrementBadgeCount();
        // Remove the notification
        await notifee.cancelNotification(notification.id);
    }
});
// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in Expo Go or in a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately

AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App)
```

I don't know what else to try. Simply, when I send requests from Firebase or FCM Tester, I can't get it to work. I have already tested, and Notifee works correctly.